# C logging framework compile time optimization

Tags: c, logging, compilation

For a certain time now, I'm looking to build a logging framework in C (not C++!), but for small microcontrollers or devices with a small footprint of some sort. For this, I've had the idea of hashing the strings that are being logged to a certain value and just saving the hashed value with the timestamp instead of the complete ASCII string. The hash can then be correlated with a 'database' file that would be generated from an external process that parses the strings out of the C source files and saves the logged strings along with the hash value.

After doing a little bit of research, this idea is not new, but I do not find an implementation of this idea in C. In other languages, this idea has been worked out, but that is not the goal of my exercise. An example may be this talk where the same concept has been worked out in C++: youtube.com/watch?v=Dt0vx-7e_B0

Some of the requirements that I've set myself for this library are the following:

- as portable C code as possible
- COMPILE TIME optimization/hashing for the string hash conversion, it should be equivalent to just `printf("%d\n", hashed_value)` for a single log statement. (Assuming no parameters/arguments for this particular logging statement).
- arguments can be passed to the logging statement similar to the printf function.
- user can define their own output function (being console, file descriptor, sending the data directly over an UART connection,...)
- fast to run!! fast to compile is nice to have, but it should not be terribly slow.
- very easy to use, no very complicated API to use the library.

But to achieve this in C, what is a good approach? I've tried several things now, but do not seem to have found a good method of achieving this.

An overview of things I've tried so far, along with the drawbacks are:

- Full pre-processor string hashing: did get it working, but the compile time is terribly slow. Also, this code does not feel to be very portable over multiple C compilers.
- Semi pre-processor string hashing: The idea was to generate a hash for each string and make an external header file with the defines in of each string with their hash value. The problem here is that I cannot figure out a way of converting the string to the correct define preprocessor value.
- Letting go of the default logging macro with a string pointer: Instead of working with the most used method of `LOG_DEBUG("Some logging statement")`, converting it with an external parser to `/*LOG_DEBUG("Some logging statement") */ LOG_RAW(45)`. This solves the problem of hashing the string since the hash will be replaced by the external parser with the correct hash, but is not the cleanest to read since the original statement will be a comment.
  Also expanding this idea to take care of arguments proved to be tricky. How to take care of multiple types of variables as efficiently as possible?

I've tried some other methods but all without success. Especially when I want to add arguments to log the value of a variable, for example, it gets very complicated, and I do not get the required result...

Comment: What strings are you hashing?  Canned ones from your logger API, or whatever free-form ones developers write for logging calls?

Comment: Is your logging going to include timestamp information?  How many of your messages will include other information specific to that logged message (relevant variables, etc.)?  The timestamp stuff may be tangential to the problem, but most messages should probably include some.  Maybe you hash the format and record the parameters?  But an 'obvious' way of handling that is an error message number plus the parameters relevant to this occurrence.

Comment: The timestamp would not be added by default. The idea was to add the timestamp at the receiver side (uart reader that will read the data from the MCU). Or it could be added when writing to a flash block device for example (SD card).
All the other data can be added to the 'database' file in my opinion to decode the logs from the uart stream or the SD card storage. Extra metadata could be file, line, level, function, extra variables with their type, ...
The strings would indeed be free form ones that the developer can write themselves. Since writing it in C, the printf format would be ideal.